# Initialize multidimensional array inside solidity function

Tags: solidity, foundry

I am writing a foundry test that calls a function "executeBatch" of another contract. "executeBatch" function accepts 4 arguments and one of the arguments is a dynamic two-dimensional array.

My question is how can I initialize a multidimensional dynamic memory array inside a solidity function?

My foundry test function snippet :

```
        ...
        ...

        uint256 _signaturesRequired = multiSigWallet.signaturesRequired();
        bytes[][] memory _signatures = new bytes[][](2);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            for (uint256 j = 0; j < _signaturesRequired; j++) {
                _signatures[i][j] = _getSignature(
                    signersPrivKeys[j],
                    _hashes[i]
                ); // I get out of index error here. 
            }
        }
        vm.deal(address(multiSigWallet), 1 ether);
        vm.prank(signers[0]);
        multiSigWallet.executeBatch(_receivers, _values, _data, _signatures);

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            assertEq(_receivers[i].balance, 0.1 ether);
        }
    }
```

Here is the function signature of the function that I am calling from my test function.

```
function executeBatch(
        address[] calldata to,
        uint256[] calldata value,
        bytes[] calldata data,
        bytes[][] calldata signatures
    ) public onlyOwner returns (bytes[] memory) {
        ...
        ...

    }
```

Comment: can you share the errors you get when you try to deploy/compile this contract?